# `np.dot` without cartesian product on remaining axes

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> For N dimensions `dot` is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last of `b`:
>
> ```
> dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
> ```

I would like to compute the sum product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last of `b` but without forming the Cartesian product over the remaining axes because the remaining axes are of the same shape. Let me illustrate with an example:

```
a = np.random.normal(size=(11, 12, 13))
b = np.random.normal(size=(11, 12, 13, 13))
c = np.dot(a, b)
c.shape # = (11, 12, 11, 12, 13)
```

But I would like the shape to be `(11, 12, 13)`. The desired effect can be achieved using broadcasting

```
c = np.sum(a[..., None] * b, axis=-2)
c.shape # = (11, 12, 13)
```

But my arrays are relatively large and I'd like to use the power of parallelised BLAS implementations which don't appear to be supported by `np.sum` but are supported by `np.dot`. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
c = np.einsum('ijk,ijkl->ijl',a,b)
```

Comment: I really like `einsum` but it doesn't parallelise using BLAS.

Comment: @TillHoffmann Well, AFAIK, dot based funcs like `np.dot` and `np.tensordot` that use `blas` won't allow aligned axes, like with `einsum` here we are keeping the first two axes aligned between `a` and `b`. On performance, for the sample datasizes, this `einsum` approach is proving to be `4x+` better :)

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification. For anyone who's interested, `np.einsum('...i,...ij->...j', a, b)` is agnostic to dimensionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`np.matmul`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

```
c = np.matmul(a[..., None, :], b)[..., 0, :]
```

This is equivalent to [the new `@` operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) in Python 3.5+:

```
c = (a[..., None, :] @ b)[..., 0, :]
```

There's not much difference in performance - if anything `np.einsum` seems to be marginally faster for your example arrays:

```
In [1]: %%timeit a = np.random.randn(11, 12, 13); b = np.random.randn(11, 12, 13, 13)
   ....: np.einsum('...i,...ij->...j', a, b)
   ....: 
The slowest run took 5.24 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an
intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.7 µs per loop

In [2]: %%timeit a = np.random.randn(11, 12, 13); b = np.random.randn(11, 12, 13, 13)
np.matmul(a[..., None, :], b)[..., 0, :]
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 28 µs per loop
```